# Form Validation with Success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I submit the form without filling in any information it quickly displays the error message then fades. I only want the form to fade if there's no error messages and the validation is successful. I think I may need to use an if statement for success or something to do with a submit handler?

So far I have this - https://jsfiddle.net/wnmLmcm8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: this.method,
      url: this.action,
      data: {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val()
      },
      success: function () {
        $('#emailform').fadeOut("slow");
      }
    });
  });

  $("form").validate({
    rules: {
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: "http://localhost:3000/inputValidator"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What does your input Validator look like?

Comment: When i ran it, the submit function handler wasnt firing.

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to work this one out for a bit! If it helps the problem is on my website here 'www.gavwellis.com' it's the form at the bottom. If you just click submit it does validate but then just fade's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version of your jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ywhpdLen/3/

This snippet works, based off of your jsFiddle, but your jsFiddle does not work. I had to pull the code into my own dev environment, locally.

The popup stays until you click in the text field.

Adding "required" to the input elements & using the default ".validate()" extension does the job. If you're looking to customize it, I'd highly recommend looking at https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

```
<div id="emailform">
    <form method="post" action="form.php">
        <hr>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="NewsLetter1" required/>
        <br>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="NewsLetter2" required/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <hr>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: this.method,
                url: this.action,
                data: {
                    name: $('#name').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val()
                },
                success: function () {
                    $('#emailform').fadeOut("slow");
                },
                failure: function (ex) {

                }
            });
        });

        $("form").validate();
    });

</script>
```

Per comments, below: It looks like your ajax call is still happening and form.submit() is firing off. You may want to remove your form.submit() call and include it in the validate call, like so.

```
 $("form").validate({
    submitHandler:function(form){

          $.ajax({....})
    }

  });
```

Comment: I'll test this out not, much appreciated

Comment: only problem is, it still fades even if the validation fails? www.gavwellis.com try it, i've just updated it!I used your code

Comment: That is because you are not checking if the form data is valid before doing your ajax.submit call. You will want to look into https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid

Comment: isn't just '$("form").validate();' doing that?

Comment: It looks like form.validate() is not preventing the ajax call, but you wouldn't know unless you debugged it and stepped through.

Comment: The documentation for jQuery.validate() suggests you can call submit() upon a valid input. @charlietfl provided it in his solution. I'll add it to mine.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with submit handler like...

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("form#sub_form").validate({
        rules: {
            UserName: "required",
            Useremail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            Userpwd:{
                required: true,
                minlength:8
            },
            Con_Userpwd:{
                required:true,
                equalTo:"#reg-pass"
            },
            contact:{
                required:true,
                minlength:10
            }
        },
        messages: {
            UserName: "Please specify your name",
            Useremail: {
                required: "We need your email address to contact you",
                email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
            },
            Userpwd:{
                required: "Enter Your Password",
                minlength:"Please Enter minimum 8 digit password"
            },
            Con_Userpwd: {
                required:"Please re-enter  your password",
                equalTo:"Password not matched"
            },
            contact:{
                required:"Phone Number Required",
                minlength:"Minimum 10 Digits Required"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var msg = $("form#sub_form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "register_checkout.php",
                    data: msg,
                    success: function (html) {
                                                                $(".popup").delay(5000).fadeOut(1500);
                            setTimeout(function(){window.location='one-page-checkout.php'},3000);
                            //return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#reg_message").slideUp();
                            $("#reg_message").slideDown().html(html);

                        }
                    }
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your ajax into `submitHandler` of validation plugin

```
  $("form").validate({
    rules: {
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: "http://localhost:3000/inputValidator"
      }
    },
    submitHandler:function(form){

          $.ajax({....})
    }

  });
```

When running into problems use `debug:true`

Answer (score 0):

for instant solution use "required" [https://jsfiddle.net/et7qcrye/](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/et7qcrye/)

```
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="NewsLetter1" required/>
```